# She is a confident and a practical speaker who always impress/impresses the audience

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> She is a confident and a practical speaker who always ***impress/impresses*** the audience

What should I use here **impress or impresses** and why?

This question was asked in an exam and they gave **impress** as the answer.

I think here **impresses** should be used as **She** is a singular pronoun and we know verb in its basic form is plural and when we add s/es, the verb becomes singular.

Comment: What do you think and why? We do expect contributors here to do a bit of their own research. I would drop the second _a_ by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the information, edited the question and showed my thinking, if you have some idea about it kindly explain. @mdewey

Comment: Your explanation is good! :) But only one a, as mdeway said is needed.

Comment: If you've copied the question perfectly, then the answer on the exam is wrong. "Impresses" is correct. Also, if you have copied the question perfectly, then it was written by someone not familiar enough with English to be writing English exams.

Comment: "practical" seems wrong: "practiced speaker" is more usual, meaning well-experienced.

Answer (score 3):

The verb agrees with the subject.  The subject is "who" which refers to "she" so the verb has third-person-singular form:

> ... who impresses..

Comment: Thanks, I also agree with you.